# Reduce scene height/width and place canvas into div

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a Three.js project which you can find over [here](http://codepen.io/lexa-r/pen/jyOoLa) in its entirety.

As you can see, there is a substantial amount of vertical, unoccupied space surrounding the particles. I was wondering if it was possible to reduce that. If not, is it possible to put it inside a div? I tinkered around with `renderer.setSize`, but it also stretched the scene; meanwhile putting it inside a div did not produce any result for me.

Unfortunately, the formal training I received in regard to web design and development was scarce, only covering the basics and rudiments; thus, I had to try to understand things such as this online so I apologize if this sounds inane.

```
var SEPARATION = 70, AMOUNTX = 25, AMOUNTY = 20;

var container, camera, scene, renderer;

var particles, particle, count = 0;

var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 1000;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

particles = new Array();

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

color: 0x333399,
program: function ( context ) {

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
  context.fill();

}

} );

var i = 0;

for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

  particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Sprite( material );
  particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
  particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
  scene.add( particle );


}

}

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({alpha:true});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

//

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

//

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;

}

function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

event.preventDefault();

mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

}

}

function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

event.preventDefault();

mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;

}

}

//

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

render();
}

function render() {

var i = 0;

for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

  particle = particles[ i++ ];
  particle.position.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) * 50 ) +
    ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) * 50 );
  particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) + 1 ) * 4 +
    ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 5;

  }

 }

renderer.render( scene, camera );

count += 0.1;

}
```

Comment: Please include your code in your post. If your link ever dies, so does the context of your question.

Comment: @TheJim01: Edited to put a snippet of code. Didn't know which part to paste in honestly and I'd put everything in if it weren't far too long.

Comment: Don't worry about the size. Just put it at the bottom of your post, so your question is most prominent. The more information you provide, the better your chances of getting a good answer, and you will provide insight and content for future readers.

Comment: @TheJim01: Thank you very much for the advice, will absolutely keep that in mind. Edited again to fit in the entire code.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you either want: 1) your dots to cover more vertical space, or 2) your canvas to be shorter so it barely contains your moving dots. Is this correct? If so, which is preferred?

Comment: @TheJim01: The second, just to clear the excess vertical space which the dots do not touch at all, if possible.

Comment: (1) `camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, ... );` will fill the space. Or (2) move the camera closer.

Comment: @WestLangley: Not quite what I'm looking for as I'd like to maintain the distance (if possible), else the particles would look rather large. Regardless, thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a fixed height for you canvas and use it inside **onWindowResize** function and **init** function.

For example:

```
// set a fixed canvas height 
var fixedCanvasHeight = 200;

function init(){
    // give separation a new value for a better particle distribution 
    SEPARATION = window.innerWidth/AMOUNTX;
    ...
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / fixedCanvasHeight, 1, 10000 );
    ...
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, fixedCanvasHeight );
    ...
}

function onWindowResize() {        
    // give separation a new value for a better particle distribution 
    SEPARATION = window.innerWidth/AMOUNTX;

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / fixedCanvasHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, fixedCanvasHeight );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! However, I was wondering whether or not it's possible to keep the aspect ratio and distance? Even with fixedCanvasHeight, there is still excess vertical space around the dot particles.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? I've combined what cameraman and WestLangley were suggesting:

- I used globalized `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` variables
- `HEIGHT` is a fixed value
- Adjust `camera.fov` to zoom to fit what you want

```js
var SEPARATION = 70,
  AMOUNTX = 25,
  AMOUNTY = 20,
  // Globalized width & height varialbes
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth, // width still references the window width
  HEIGHT = 200; // height is now a fixed value (if this needs to be dynamic, you'll need to calculate it)

var container, camera, scene, renderer, particles, particle, count = 0;

var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;

var windowHalfX = WIDTH / 2;
var windowHalfY = HEIGHT / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10000); // smaller FOV = tighter zoom
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  particles = new Array();

  var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
  var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial({
    color: 0x333399,
    program: function(context) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true);
      context.fill();
    }
  });

  var i = 0;

  for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
    for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
      particle = particles[i++] = new THREE.Sprite(material);
      particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTX * SEPARATION) / 2);
      particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ((AMOUNTY * SEPARATION) / 2);
      scene.add(particle);
    }
  }

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

  //

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

}

function onWindowResize() {
  windowHalfX = WIDTH / 2;
  windowHalfY = HEIGHT / 2;
  camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
  mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;
}

function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {
  if (event.touches.length === 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
  }
}

function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {
  if (event.touches.length === 1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
    mouseY = event.touches[0].pageY - windowHalfY;
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  var i = 0;
  for (var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix++) {
    for (var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy++) {
      particle = particles[i++];
      particle.position.y = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) * 50) +
        (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) * 50);
      particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = (Math.sin((ix + count) * 0.3) + 1) * 4 +
        (Math.sin((iy + count) * 0.5) + 1) * 5;
    }
  }
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  count += 0.1;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. Second of all, what I wanted was something like [this](http://imgur.com/a/mWPuC) where the distance and the size of the dot particles are uniform across different browser sizes. And lastly, if this is something that is actually impossible/difficult to achieve, or very inconvenient, then I'm sorry.

Comment: @LexaR Try changing the value of the `WIDTH` variable. You'll see that it scales like you're describing. Positioning the canvas is a different matter, and can be accomplished through CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you have troubles putting the canvas into a `div`. Of course, within a `div` you can position and size the canvas much better.

Here the basic code snippets from your updated example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybBVYX

```js
var SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT;

// init
container = $('.webgl');
SCREEN_WIDTH = container.width();
SCREEN_HEIGHT = container.height();

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 1000;

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({alpha:true});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
container.append( renderer.domElement );

// resize
function onWindowResize() {

  SCREEN_WIDTH = container.width();
  SCREEN_HEIGHT = container.height();
  
  camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

}
```

```css
html, body {
  color: #ff0000;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  height: 60%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.webgl {
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p class="test">Hello</p>
  <a href="">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="webgl"></div>
```

If you want to keep the aspect ratio, then you would need to set the width or height of your div and the canvas element explicitly, e.g. using jQuery:

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = container.width();
SCREEN_HEIGHT = SCREEN_WIDTH * aspectRatio;

container.height( SCREEN_HEIGHT );
```